# How to avoid splitting of word with case

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-4.0

Below is the text that I want to split:

```
string content = "Tonight the warning from the Police commissioner as they crack down on anyone who leaves there house without a 'reasonable excuse' 
(TAKE SOT)"

string[] contentList = content.split(' ');
```

I do not want to split the word i.e (TAKE SOT), if there is a text within parentheses and in an upper case then how to avoid splitting of the part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The split method can have two parameters.The first one delimits the substrings in this instance.The second one  is the maximum number of elements expected in the array.

The following code snippet work for me, you can refer to it.

```
string content = "Tonight the warning from the Police commissioner as they crack down on anyone who leaves there house without a 'reasonable excuse' (TAKE SOT)";
            string[] contents = content.Split(" ", content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("(")).Split(" ").Length);
```

And this is the result of the code:
[image]

I use the method Split(String, Int32, StringSplitOptions)
[image]

[image]

Comment: content.Split(" ", content.Substring(0, content.IndexOf("(")).Split(" ").Length) , it gives me an error that can't convert from string to char.

Comment: I updated my answer,I used the method Split(String, Int32, StringSplitOptions),And I am afraid you used the method Split(Char, Int32, StringSplitOptions).

Comment: Can you add a running example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Do you mean you use .net 4.7.2 rather than .net core 3.1.If in .net core3.1,the method is available.You can run it on local.

Comment: If I have more then one (TAKE) or (TAKE SOT) or (VO) in a string content then it's not working accordingly.

Comment: I have found a solution for this, we can use the regex i.e @"\(([A-Z\s]*)\)", where it matches we can add that word in a list and we can split the string via getting the length of matched one and split the whole string into words using space character and add it to the list of string.

Answer (score 0):

Later after doing some research I found a solution for the problem:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT = @"\(([A-Z\s]*)\)";
        List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
        string content = "Tonight the warning from the Police commissioner as they (VO) crack down on anyone who leaves there house without a 'reasonable excuse' (TAKE SOT) INCUE:police will continue to be out there.";
        GetWords(content, wordList, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT);

        foreach(var item in wordList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }           
    }

    private static void GetWords(string content, List<string> wordList, string BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT)
    {
        if(content.Length>0)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(content, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT))
            {
                int textLength = content.Substring(0, Regex.Match(content, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT).Index).Length;
                int matchLength = Regex.Match(content, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT).Length;
                string[] words = content.Substring(0, Regex.Match(content, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT).Index - 1).Split(' ');
                foreach (var word in words)
                {
                    wordList.Add(word);
                }
                wordList.Add(content.Substring(Regex.Match(content, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT).Index, Regex.Match(content, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT).Length));
                content = content.Substring((textLength + matchLength) + 1); // Remaining content
                GetWords(content, wordList, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT); 
            }
            else
            {
               wordList.Add(content);
               content = content.Substring(content.Length); // Remaining content
               GetWords(content, wordList, BEFORE_AND_AFTER_SOUND_EFFECT);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.